# Wagtail unit testing: Adding child pages converts them to base type

Tags: django, django-testing, wagtail

Trying to create some unit tests for Wagtail and running into the following problem:

```
>> root = FrontPage.add_root(instance=FrontPageFactory.build())
>> root
<FrontPage: article0>

>> root.add_child(instance=ArticlePageFactory.build())
<ArticlePage: article1>

>> root.get_tree()
<PageQuerySet [<Page: article0>, <Page: article1>]>
```

"article0" goes from being type ArticlePage to type Page in the page tree.  Is this Page object a reference to the ArticlePage and there's a method I'm not aware of to fetch it, or am I missing something obvious here?

In the meantime I've worked around the problem by just storing the added article pages in a separate list, but I'd really like to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wagtail uses [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) to represent pages: the fields that are common to all page types (such as title and slug, along with various internal ones used for things like tracking position within the page tree) are part of the base `Page` model that all page types inherit from. The additional fields you define on `ArticlePage` exist separately in their own table. When you retrieve a page instance, it can exist in one of two possible forms depending on which model you retrieve it through:

```
>> page = Page.objects.get(title='article1')
<Page: article1>
```

This is a basic `Page` instance, and only has access to properties like `page.title`, not fields/methods defined on `ArticlePage`.

```
>> page = ArticlePage.objects.get(title='article1')
<ArticlePage: article1>
```

This is a full `ArticlePage` instance, allowing you to refer to things like `page.body`.

Operations that traverse the page tree, such as `get_tree()` or `get_children()`, always give you basic `Page` instances. This is for performance reasons - there's no way to know in advance which page types you're going to get back, so it can't tell which tables to query in order to retrieve the full page data.

You can go from an individual `Page` instance into an instance of the more specific page model, by accessing the `specific` property - this will incur one extra database query:

```
>> page = Page.objects.get(title='article1')
>> page.specific
<ArticlePage: article1>
```

You can also call the `specific()` method on a `PageQuerySet`, which will perform one extra query for each distinct page type that exists in that queryset:

```
>> root.get_tree().specific()
<PageQuerySet [<FrontPage: article0>, <ArticlePage: article1>]>
```